# Dependence of the Capacitance on the Material and Geometry of the Plates

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, capacitance

I have two questions concerning capacitors:

1) We know that the capacitance of a capacitor also depend on the dielectric material inside as

$C=$ $\dfrac{K \epsilon_0 A}{d}$

But what if the material *itself*  with which the capacitor is made is changed? So is there different values for a capacitor made of iron and one made of copper? Will it follow the same formula?

2) What if we put another plate inside one capacitor either parallely or obliquely as

**Initially:**

[image]

**Modified:**

[image]

**OR:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You're asking about non ideal capacitors (see e.g. [here](http://www.ecestudents.ul.ie/Course_Pages/MEng_CS/Modules/EE6471/web/lecture%20notes/Microsoft%20PowerPoint%20-%20EE6471%20Lecture3.pdf)), i.e. answer to your question is 'yes'. The formula assumes that capacitor's plates are the perfect conductors. 
2) Oblique - will not work since you connect the plates, the last one can be decomposed into three capacitors joined in parallel.